# Overriding variables in multiple scss files

Tags: sass

If I have a structure like this:

```
|_styles
        |
         ___ _colors.scss
|_components
        |_input
              |_input.tsx
              |_input.scss
        |label
              |_label.tsx
              |_label.scss
```

And if each component is importing the scss file like this:

`import './input.scss';`

And each scss file is like this:

```scss
@import '_colors.scss';

.default {
  color: $label-default-color;
}
```

I want to export this library as a package and then be able to default the variables in `_colors.scss`, but how can I do that if each .scss file is importing the `_colors.scss` file?

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

To override a Sass variable, you can simply set a new value.

**_color.scss:**

```scss
// DEFAULT LABEL COLOR
// Note: You can use the !default flag to make sure it
// doesn't override custom colors defined in other files
$label-default-color: red !default;
```

**_label.scss:**

```scss
// OVERRIDE LABEL COLOR
$label-default-color: blue;
```